# Batch file. If variable contains string value then goto update password

Tags: batch-file

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the below for me.

I have 4 accounts lets call them
ABC1, ABC2, ABC3, ABC4

I have 60 remote machine that this script will execute on so they all get pulled via serverlist.txt with command.

```
For /f %%i in (C:\Temp\app\serverlist.txt) do ()
```

serverlist.txt contains hostnames like

```
ABCSYDJ12345
ABCSYDJ12123
ABCMELJ12124
ABCBNEJ12133
```

Now when the batch file reads each line in the serverlist.txt i want it to check if the first 6 characters of the hostname contain a certain value then goto certain script.

Example:

```
For /f %%i in (C:\Temp\app\serverlist.txt) do (
IF %%i (FIRST 6 CHARCTERS)==ABCSYD GOTO Host1
IF %%i (FIRST 6 CHARCTERS)==ABCMEL GOTO Host2

::HOST1
Echo. Executing script on host 1 with username ABC1

::HOST2
Echo. Executing script on host 2 with username ABC2
)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (serverlist.txt) do (

set temp=%%A
echo !temp:~0,6!

IF "!temp:~0,6!"=="ABCSYD" call :host1

IF "!temp:~0,6!"=="ABCMEL" call :host2

)
pause
Goto :eof

:host1
Echo Executing script on host 1 with username ABC1
Goto :eof

:host2
Echo Executing script on host 2 with username ABC2
Goto :eof
```

I found out that if using GOTO inside the for loop, it will still forget the context. So, I replace it with CALL.

Hope it helps.